# How to reference the contents of a .a file (c++)

Tags: c++, .a

I was provided with a file file named libfunctions.a
It contains functions that I need to reference in my program.
for example, if the user inputs '1', it should use function f1 in the libfunctions file

I am also provided with test.sh, bench.sh, and a makefile
If my program was correct, I should be able to test it using "make test", but when I do that, it outputs:
make: execvp: ./test.sh: Permission denied
make: *** [test] Error 127

Comment: Normally you'll have a `.h` file that goes with it, too.

Comment: That's called a *static library*. How do you compile your code?

Comment: You can use the program `nm` to get the contents on Linux and at the DOS prompt, but that probably won't be enough information for you to write your program.  You're going that .h file or to reverse engineer the equivalent yourself.

Comment: Sorry, its the first time I ask a question and forgot to give more info.
I can't really compile the code because it is calling the functions in the .a file but it can't actually reference it

Comment: when ever I try to compile it I just get "  undefined reference to `f1'"

Comment: `chmod +x test.sh`. And take some classes that teach your Linux.